# How do I minimise the maximum aspect ratio of two subpolygons?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, partitioning, computational-geometry

I'd like to cut a convex polygon into two with a given ratio of areas using a straight line, such that the larger aspect ratio of the two subpolygons is minimised.

My approach at the moment involves choosing a random starting point, computing the appropriate end point that splits the polygon into the target areas, then calculating the larger of the two aspect ratios.  Then repeating this lots of times until I'm close enough to a minimum!

The aspect ratio of a polygon A is defined as:

`asp(A) := diam(A)^2 / area(A)`

Comment: I think I know an approach, but I need a clarification. What do you mean with minimizing "the larger aspect ratio of the two subpolygons"? I read this as "place the cut such that the difference in aspect ratios between the two subpolygons is minimized". Is that correct?

Comment: And, I take it that diam(A) is defined as in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonDiameter.html, right?

Comment: Any constraints on the area ratio? Am I free in determining which is area1 and which area2 in area1/area2? IOW, can I make this ratio always >=1?

Comment: @Sjoerd I think the key is "with a given ratio" (ie with an arbitrary pre-specified ratio)

Comment: @Sjoerd Actually I want to place the cut such that the maximum of the two aspect ratios is minimised, not minimise the difference.

Comment: @Sjoerd And yes, your assumption about `diam(A)` is correct.

Comment: @Jason but what, if during your aspect ratio minimization the aspect ratio of the first gets lower than that of the second? Then the first one isn't the largest any more and you stop. Effectively, you then have minimized the difference between the two aspect ratios. Admittedly, this doesn't have to happen.

Comment: @Sjoerd Hmm, yes, you are probably right. I can't think of a case where your reasoning wouldn't apply. Useful way of looking at it!

Comment: @Jason Well, I assume it is possible that the range of possible aspect ratios of area1 depending on the shape of 'yellow area' taken is always higher than the range taken by area2. In that case you can fully minimize area1's aspect ratio. The question is purely: what do _you_ want? Always minimize the area that has the highest _possible_ aspect ratio, or minimize the difference, or perhaps, minimize the sum of both aspect ratios?

Comment: The idea is to generate the "most aesthetically pleasing" cut (which means low aspect ratios), so I think if the biggest of the two is minimised this will achieve the desired result.  This *seems* like the same as minimising the difference between the two but presumably this only holds if decreasing one aspect ratio leads to an increase in the other (which I *think* is the case!)

Comment: @jason That's not necessarily the case (i.e., increasing one implies decreasing another). The aspect ratio of an area may _increase_ if I enlarge that area with a relatively narrow area (long diag, small extra area), but it may also _decrease_ by adding area if that added area is relatively plump (little or no added diag, with added area)

Comment: @belisarius @jason I'm finished with my work on the polygon question and made an (hopefully last) update.

Comment: @Sjoerd I can upvote your answer only one time. But you deserve much more. Well done!

Comment: Many thanks to both of you, I've marked @Sjoerd's answer as the accepted one but I'm overwhelmed by the level of detail and hard work that's gone into this. I'd given up hope of an answer after the first couple of days so when I got an email notifying me of *two* answers I was overjoyed!

Comment: @Jason Your problem is not a simple one. It took us a lot of time to come up with these answers ;)

Comment: @belisarius and @jason Thanks!  I enjoyed doing it, although it took more than I originally planned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method I've been working on is very similar to Belisarius, so I'll only share a few notes about my thinking (I'm using Mathematica).

- The number of edge pairs in which the cut may be placed is quadratically in the number of vertices (1/2 n (n-1) ): (lines mark edge pairs, by connecting the starting vertices of each pair)

[image]

The yellow areas mark the area were one could locate the cut:

[image]

so before doing many calculations on all combinations it's good to mow away invalid candidates. Here is shown for some area ratios what pairs are left:

[image]
 - As belisarius says you can find the range of area ratios for each of the above situations, but simply taking the Min and Max is incorrect. The two ranges you get when you reverse the two areas in your area ratio maybe disjunct. I use Mathematica's `Interval` arithmetic to handle this for me:

[image]

Checking whether a given area ratio is also handled with a comfortable Interval function:

```
containsRatioQ[area1_, area2_, areaBetween_, ratio_] := 
 IntervalMemberQ[areaRatioInterval[area1, area2, areaBetween], ratio]
```

- The value of the paramater labda that determines the location of the cut through the first edge as a function of mu (the parameter that determined the position for the second edge)

  `\[Lambda] -> (2*aL + givenAreaRatio*(-2*
         aR + (p1y - p3y)*(p2x - p4x) - (p1x - p3x)*(p2y - p4y)) + (1 + 
        givenAreaRatio)*(p1x*p3y - p3y*p4x + p1y*(-p3x + p4x) - 
        p1x*p4y + p3x*p4y)*\[Mu])/
     ((1 + givenAreaRatio)*((-p2x)*p4y + 
       p1x*(-p2y + p4y) + (p1x - p2x)*(p3y - p4y)*\[Mu] + 
       p1y*(p2x + p4x*(-1 + \[Mu]) - p3x*\[Mu]) + 
       p2y*(p4x + p3x*\[Mu] - p4x*\[Mu])))`

or mu as a function of labda:

```
\[Mu] -> (-2*aL + givenAreaRatio*(2*
       aR - (p1y - p3y)*(p2x - p4x) + (p1x - p3x)*(p2y - p4y)) + (1 + 
      givenAreaRatio)*((-p1x)*p2y + p1y*(p2x - p4x) + p2y*p4x + 
      p1x*p4y - p2x*p4y)*\[Lambda])/
   ((1 + givenAreaRatio)*((-p3y)*p4x + p3x*p4y + 
     p1y*(p3x - p4x)*(-1 + \[Lambda]) - 
     p1x*(p3y - p4y)*(-1 + \[Lambda]) + ((-p2y)*p3x + p2x*p3y + 
        p2y*p4x - p2x*p4y)*\[Lambda]))
```

with p1, p2, p3, p4 the coordinates of the area embracing the cut and aL the area of the 'green' polygon and aR the area of the 'red' polygon (see figure at the bottom of this post).

- Not every point on one edge always gives a solution on the other edge and vice versa. I check the equation for lambda to find values of mu which set lambda at 0 or 1, and vice versa.
- As a last step I minimize the maximum value of the aspect ratio functions of the two areas. In Mathematica language:

  `NMinimize[{Max[aspectRatio[area1tot], aspectRatio[area2tot]], \[Mu]range[[1]] <= \[Mu] <= \[Mu]range[[2]]}, \[Mu]]`

with are1tot and area2tot being the total areas for both halves parametrized by mu and lambda and where lambda is replaced by the above equestion for lambda in terms of mu. Now we have only one parameter left

- Here is the result for the minimization procedure for an area ratio of 1. The green curve is the aspect ratio for the green polygon (+ added area depending on mu) and the red curve is the aspect ratio for the red polygon (+ added area depending on mu).

[image]

- And here, finally, is your 'most pleasing' polygon cut:

[image]

I have a Mathematica notebook that I will send on request. Just send me an e-mail.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, thanks very much!  I need some time to digest the part about `Interval` as I'm not quite sure what "The two ranges you get when you reverse the two areas in your area ratio maybe disjunct" means.

Comment: @Jason It's actually not that difficult (although it took me some time myself before I realized it, to be honest).  If, for instance, the area ratio of (area1+part of yellow)/(area2+other part of yellow area) ranges between 2 and 4 then it also possible to have a ratio between 1/4 and 1/2. This means that there is a hole in the range you can cover between 1/2 and 2. So, you have two disjunct ratio areas. If, on the other hand, the first range is 0.8 to 2, the second range is 0.5 to 1.25, giving a total range of 0.5 to 2, without holes. `Interval` takes care of that automatically.

Comment: @Jason [cont.] ... In other languages you'd have to rely on a bunch of IF's and comparisons.

Comment: @Sjoerd I started a bounty. I think you deserve it!

Comment: @belisarius great, thanks! I feel this is very much the product of both of us, though. We shared the basic idea and your area equation really help finishing this thing. Anyway, the bounty will help bridging the meager weeks ahead of me, where I only will have iPhone access to SO. :)

Comment: @Sjoerd Hope you are going on vacation!

Comment: Wow, thanks, the aspect ratio graphs illustrate the minimisation procedure really well!

This is certainly enough for me to run with now, but my next question is whether there is an exact solution to the minimisation procedure i.e. without using an optimisation procedure like `NMinimize`.  I suppose if I look at it hard enough I can come up with some if statements that check the slopes for each parameterised range.

Don't worry if you don't have an answer to this though, I'm more than happy with your answer to my original question.

Comment: @Jason I think the problem lies in the aspect ratio. The diag term is the longest distance between two vertices and this may change suddenly even when you increase the cut area gradually. A new pair may become the current winner. I assume this explains the sudden slope changes in the curve. A closed form equation for diag without the non-linar 'Max' function is not likely to be found IMO. Another jump the minimalization procedure has to deal with is when the two aspect ratio curves cross. Given that you pick the largest one to minimalize you have a slope jump again.

Answer (score 5):

I'll write down a sketched answer first, and probably expand it if you are interested in going along these lines. I've a program running to compute this in Mathematica, (with some restrictions), and I'll also post it if I get some time to finish it.

The problem has actually two parts:

- Find the polygon partitions which yields your desired area ratio
- Select from them the one that minimizes the aspect ratio

Let's see the first problem first. You could do something like:

Consider each pair of sides, like in the following figure

[image]

And for each pair, consider the three following areas:

[image]

So, the maximal and minimal ratios that you may get for partitioning the polygon with a line crossing these two sides are the `Min()` and `Max[]` of the following set:

```
 { (S1+S2)/S3, S3/(S1+S2), (S2+S3)/S1, S1/(S2+S3) }
```

If your desired ratio is not between the Max and Min of this set, discard the pair.

**NB:** For calculating areas you may use [**this formula**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html)

Once you get all the candidate pair of sides, the problem is to find a function of only one parameter that describes all possible partitions of the quadrilateral that respects the desired ratio.

If you parametrize both sides with an equation like

```
{x, y} = {A} + t {B- A}
```

you will be able to get something like this:

[image]

And you can find the green area using the same formula, depending upon the two parameters (one for each side). I uploaded it to [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/CU3AW), just because it is too clumsy to post here

The next step is reducing the problem to only one parameter. This is done taking into account that you desire a certain area ratio for your complete polygon.

From that two equations you get a relationship (an hyperbola) between both parameters for each pair of sides. All those cuts have the desired area ratio.

Next thing is calculating the aspect ratio, and selecting the minimum. As the functions are pretty smooth, all you need to do is to program an extreme finder.

here you can see the results for the aspect ratio for an hexagon, taking one vertex as a split point like this:

[image]

And the aspect ratio plot for each area is:

[image]

Where each unit in the x axis corresponds to one side.

Let me know if you want more details ...

Comment: This is basically the same approach I'm working on for since you pointed me in this direction (that is 1.5 days). I didn't know about the polygon area equation. So I do a Delauny triangulation and sum the area of all the triangles. 

I have now functions to 1) cut up a polygon in three sets, 2) determine the possible area ratios for every segment pair 3) check whether a given area ratio can be made there 4) find all segment pairs that should be studied. I have the hyperbola and the other function. Your assumption about the Min and Max of the ratio set is wrong BTW!!

Comment: @Sjoerd I like your approach, so +1. Re the min-max _assumption_, the evident flaw is that it doesn't account for cuts involving two adjacent sides, but I didn't want to complicate my sketched solution with nuisances. Is there any other thing wrong with that? I fail to see it :*(

Comment: And +1 to you too. Your area calculation is orders faster. This was my first use of Interval. Nice. Automatic sorting of the ends, automatic joining. Works great here. Did you see your solution is correct only if one range includes 1 and wrong otherwise?

Comment: Fascinating, thank you so much! Can you expand the last part, "all you need to do is to program an extreme finder"?  I'm curious about whether this can be solved analytically (exactly) in a similar way to finding the exact cut point for the area ratio, or the best approach to exploit the smoothness of the function.

Comment: @Sjoerd Mine was a typical example of a "jump to conclusions" attitude :). I think adding up both answers the OP has enough to kick-off. The double parametrization took me a while, as I was sure there must be a simple expression, but I wasn't able to find it. Also: I started calculating the area and diameter by rasterizing and using `ComponentMeasurements[ _, # ]&@{"Area", "BoundingDiskRadius" }` , and after that I remembered the formula.

Comment: @belisarius I'm still working on it,  and have also been doing some cleaning up. Your equation enables me to simplify a couple of things. It looks like I made an error calculating the relationship between your T(H1)&T(H2) (my mu and lambda). It seems linear and much simpler than what I posted. If I'm finished can I send may notebook to you somehow to compare?

Comment: @Sjoerd  I don't believe I'll have time to do that today :(, sorry. My email is in my profile, but it'll have to wait unopened until next week.

Comment: @Sjoerd I edited my profile lately and inadvertently removed the email. Now it is there again