# Simplify a series in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sum, simplify

I'm having some issues simplifying some functions in mathematica. In a program I wrote I have a few functions calculated with the Sum function, many of the terms end up being multiplied by zero. I want the function to be printed but simplified. I try using FullSimplify, but it takes forever to run. I then tried using Simplify, but it doesn't work. Here is an example of a function I'm getting,

```
2. Sqrt[-(-1+x) x]+
0. Sin[2 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[3 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[4 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[5 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[6 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[7 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[8 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[9 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[10 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[11 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[12 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[13 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[14 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[15 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[16 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[17 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[18 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[19 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[20 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[21 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[22 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[23 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[24 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[25 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]+
0. Sin[26 ArcCos[-1+2 x]]
```

So, why wouldn't this simplify to

```
2. Sqrt[-(-1+x) x]
```

I also have a follow up question that is not exactly as important. But, lets say four of those terms have non-zero coefficients, is it possible to combine them into one term that is a numerical approximation of the original?

Thanks to anyone that replies!

Comment: Could you clarify your second question somewhat?

Comment: I think you could simplify your question. Try `0.+x`

Comment: @Sjoerd Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459872/how-do-i-minimise-the-maximum-aspect-ratio-of-two-subpolygons

Comment: @belisarius Interesting problem, indeed. I see a line of attack. Will investigate tomorrow.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries, well I sorta realize my second question is a stupid one. What I would really love is if I could combine four of those Sin terms into a function of just one term that approximates the four terms. I'm quite doubtful that such a thing exists.

Comment: @Silmaril89: You say "approximate" but don't tell use how well it should approximate (i.e. to what order). You can always expand each term in terms of its Taylor series (use `Series[]`) and keep say the first `n` terms from each, and combine them all into one giant term with a humungous numerator and denominator (use `Together[]`). Again, this is stretching the meaning of the word "term" :)

Comment: @Silmaril89: Also look into `TrigExpand`, which uses [trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) to expand the functions. For e.g., `Sin[2 ArcSin[x]]` is `2 x Sqrt[1 - x^2]`, `Sin[3 ArcSin[x]]` is `3 x - 4 x^3`

Comment: @Yoda, thank you, I'll look into both of those.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say hello to machine precision.

```
(* exact *)
0 Sin[x]
Out[1]= 0

(* machine precision *)
0. Sin[x]
Out[2]= 0. Sin[x]
```

Use [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html?q=Chop&lang=en) to set numbers absurdly close to zero, to 0 exactly.

```
expr = 2. Sqrt[-(-1 + x) x] + 0. Sin[2 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 
   0. Sin[3 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 0. Sin[4 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 
   0. Sin[5 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 0. Sin[6 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 
   0. Sin[7 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 0. Sin[8 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 
   0. Sin[9 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 0. Sin[10 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 
   0. Sin[11 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 0. Sin[12 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 
   0. Sin[13 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 0. Sin[14 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 
   0. Sin[15 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 0. Sin[16 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]] + 
   0. Sin[17 ArcCos[-1 + 2 x]];

Chop[expr]
Out[4]= 2. Sqrt[(1 - x) x]
```

Comment: An interesting "trick" is to take a 10 digit calculator and enter 1E12 + 1 - 1E12. If the 1 is any position, but the last one, it will return 0. You can do the same with mma, although its precision is higher. On my machine, `1.*10^16 + 1. - 1.*10^16` gives 0. Note the decimal points, if all of them are removed, mma reverts to exact arithmetic and gives 1. Also, if the first terms in an expression are large, mma will sometimes ignore the small terms: see the last example [here](http://www.omninerd.com/articles/First_Rule_of_Computation_Don_t_Trust_Your_Calculator).

Answer (score 6):

Behind those "0." terms there are hidden some very tiny (but non-zero) numbers. You can slash them using `Chop`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, makes perfect sense. You deserve the check mark just as much as yoda, but I have to choose one of you.

Comment: Yoda was the better one here. I don't think my phrasing here was even technically correct.